# npm comes with node now. What does this mean?

Tags: node.js, npm

Node noob here.

I had previously installed both npm and node separately.

Apparently, npm comes with node now. ([link](https://github.com/isaacs/npm#super-easy-install))

To my newbie mind, this means my previous dual installation is old and ugly. 1 binary > 2 binaries. So i uninstalled both.

Then I installed the latest node following the [procedure](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os). (i am running eOS)

Terminal

```
user@box:-$ which node
/usr/bin/node
user@box:-$ node -v
v0.10.22
user@box:-$ which npm
user@box:-$ npm -v
bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

I can always run:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

but that seems to indicate that npm is actually NOT included in node.

When they say they are included do they just mean the code is in the same repo, but the binaries are still different?

Final question I have /usr/bin/node as well as /usr/bin/nodejs
can i delete one of these? im not sure when/where i picked up a second copy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Yes, the nodejs package includes both `node` and `npm` executables. The code for each has its own repo, but when packaged both are included.
- npm source: https://github.com/isaacs/npm
- node source: https://github.com/joyent/node
- When you install that .deb file from the PPA, you should get both `/usr/bin/nodejs` and `/usr/bin/npm` and 2 symlinks at `/usr/bin/node` (which points to) `/etc/alternatives/node` (which points to `/usr/bin/nodejs`).

  - If any of this isn't true, your install didn't fully succeed, most likely due to conflicting files you left around from your manual install. I would suggest uninstalling the .deb then making sure there are no stale files left from your manual install and then installing again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how they are connected. A lot of times stuff that is obvious to the community flies right over my head. Did a thorough cleaning and re installed and npm is there this time. #facepalm

Comment: Do you know from which version it's packaged together? I could not find online

Comment: Each release of node generally uses the stable version of npm at that time, so there are hundreds of combinations that have been released. The node project includes the copy of npm it ships, so if you want to check you can look at the version in npm's package.json here https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/npm/package.json, or you can install a specific node version and run `npm --version` from that.

Answer (score 6):

Only node.js *packages* comes with npm.  so if you are installing using an `.msi`, `.exe`, `.dmg` `.pkg`, `.deb` or using a package installer like `apt-get`, `yum` or `brew`, then you'll have both node and npm.

However,npm is not part of the node core.  if you are installing node and using a method where you are using `./configure` or `make install` || `make link`, then npm will not be installed, and will need to be compiled using the same type of installation, and node will have to be placed on your path.

If you used git, or unzipped node and you can see a configure script, then you will also need to acquire npm.

Answer (score 5):

I've had issues (mostly on Mac) with npm ending up in directories that aren't in the terminal PATH. If you can figure out where npm is located, you can just add it to your path with something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/npm
```

I think (I'm not on a mac so I can't check at the moment) that it sometimes gets put in `/usr/local/share/`. But at any rate, the problem is likely NOT that npm isn't installed, but that it's installed somewhere you're not expecting.

Comment: It worked for me, on WSL (Windows Subsystem for linux). I installed nodejs, and for node I was able to use, but npm was not available, added path for it, and not it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Few months ago i had started learning the react so all this stuff i needed to install my laptop that had the ubuntu operating system.

What i did -- First i installed the node and without knowing that it came up with the npm package. I installed the npm package again.. but there was no conflict at all.

But after exploring all these things that nodejs have npm package. So i uninstalled the npm package due to concern about memory usage..

And Now everything is working fine....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).